# Is there an efficient way to implement CLOCK cache algorithm?

Tags: algorithm, caching

The [CLOCK cache algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Page_replacement_algorithm#Clock) is quite easy to implement with a reference array recording whether an item has been reference or not, and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10122304/clock-cache-algorithm) is an example. However, it seems that the time complexity of this solution is **O(N)** (N is the capacity of the cache), since we need to iterate the reference array to find a victim whose reference bit is 0. Is there any more efficient solution?

Another question is how to support `del` operation efficiently for CLOCK algorithm? There're many resources on how to do `get` and `set` operations. But nothing mentioned about `del` operation. If some items are deleted, e.g. either explicitly deleted or expired with a TTL, there will be some *holes* in the reference array.

In this case, when we need to find a victim, the following solution should work:

- Element in reference array has 3 state: *hole*, *referenced*, *not referenced*.
- if cache is not full, iterate reference array to find a hole, and use that hole as victim. No item will be evicted. In this case, we don't move the clock hand, and untouched the state of other elements.
- if cache is full, iterate the array with moving the clock hand, to find a victim. Also modify states of elements we passed by from *referenced* to *not referenced*.

Again, this also has **O(N)** complexity. Is there any way to optimize it?

Comment: Use a linked list?

Comment: Any detail? How to use linked list to quickly find unreferenced item? [Second chance](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Page_replacement_algorithm#Second-chance) algorithm uses a list to queue items. However, this way is still O(N), and should be slower than CLOCK, since CLOCK don't need to move element, and array is faster than list.

Comment: You could use a scan threshold to evict one of the warm entries if a cold one was not found. Another idea would be to reduce the cost (but not complexity) by maintaining a bitmap rather than scan the entries directly. Otherwise there are many other policies that have higher hit rates and are O(1). [Caffeine](https://github.com/ben-manes/caffeine) has a simulator with many of these and its design docs describe a concurrency model that works for any policy.

Comment: CLOCK (and LP-FIFO, a different implementation of the same concept) are fundamentally O(n) eviction, I don't think that's something you can avoid but also not necessarily an issue: you can reduce the constant by using a separate bitmap and bit operations ("bit twiddling hacks", CPU instructions, SIMD) to count the number of ones following the clock hand and bulk unset them rather than checking them one at a time in a loop.

Comment: Unless you want to support explicit unsetting or clearing I think you can also just ignore the hole state: initially you just fill the cache buffer linearly keeping track of its size, once the size matches the capacity you transition to the eviction state, there is no need for iteration during the initial filling state.